# function prototype giving not found warning

Tags: c, visual-studio

I was writing a simple balanced bracket program related to data structures in C. Here is my function prototype and its corresponding method body:

```
int IsBracketBalanced(char[]);

int IsBracketBalanced(char bracketSequence[1000])
{
        char stack[1000];
        int isBracketBalanced = 1;

    //do something here

    return isBracketBalanced;
}
```

But Visual Studio is showing a green squiggle below the function prototype and shows a warning as

> Function definition for 'IsBracketBalanced' not found.

Is there anything wrong in my signature because of character array parameter? I've written this code in C on visual Studio 2015 with OS being Windows 7.

Comment: Are the declaration and definition in the same source file?

Comment: work for me. Are you sure that this definition is include where you use IsBracketBalanced() ?

Comment: Are you actually getting a compiler error, or is this just IntelliSense spouting noisy nonsense? This code looks completely reasonable to me.

Comment: Sure you don't use a C++ compiler? It is a different language! And you should use the **identical** parameter declaration in definition and prototype.

Comment: @Evert Yes. They are in the same source file.

Comment: @Stargateur Yes. the definition is included where I'm using it.

Comment: @CodyGray The code is compiling and running successfully.

Comment: @Olaf I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I'm using a C++ project template but I've changed the extension of the *.cpp file to *.c and set the `Compile As` option for my project to `Compile as C Code (/TC)`. I'm not sure if it uses a C compiler specifically inside but I believe this is the best way out I've to run C code inside Visual Studio

Comment: @Olaf is my prototype and definition not identical? They both are character arrays. I've mentioned the size in function definition so that compiler gets to know the size of the array I'll be passing to it at run time. I'm just trying to help the compiler but I'm wondering why it is not going down well with it. And interestingly! it just works without throwing any error at run time

Comment: @RBT: What do you think the prototype is for? **in** the function, the length is irrelevant. If you want the length, you have to pass it explicitly. That is basic C and should be detailed in every C book. To summarise: you strictly cannot pass an array to a function. Use that as premise and reserach why this statement is true (what it is).

Comment: Both array types are going to be implicitly converted to a pointer whenever you pass an argument, so while they are functionally equivalent, they may be parsed differently by the compiler. I can't remember what the differences are between what the C and C++ specs say about this behavior, but this is very likely the key. You're compiling as C code, where this is all legal. But IntelliSense uses a C++ parser, because C++ is MS's primary language focus, so it's raising a spurious warning. In this case, though, the most sensible option is just to rewrite the prototype as `char*`.

Comment: @CodyGray: The correct way and the best to document what the function expects would be a VLA with explicit length parameter, making the finction flexible and avoiding magic numbers. The second best changing the prototype to that of the declaration using a macro for the length instead of a magic number. A mere pointer would be what the compiler sees, but bad for human documentation.

Comment: A VLA would be nice, but unfortunately not supported by Microsoft's C compiler. But I'm not arguing that this is beneficial for documentation, or even that this notation is beneficial at all, so it is unclear to me the relevance of your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not exactly the same prototypes and perhaps that is confusing the code analyzer, just use

```
int IsBracketBalanced(char *, size_t);
```

instead, and of course

```
int IsBracketBalanced(char *bracketSequence, size_t size)
```

and pass the size as a parameter avoiding many problems. Many library functions like `gets()` eventually got rewritten to use this kind of prototype.

Since after all you cannot take any advantage of the fact the function takes an *array* because it's converted to a pointer anyway, there is no benefit in using `char []` except perhaps readability.

Comment: I agree with you. Just to add one thing. In my specific case the parameter `char bracketSequence[]`will hold a null terminated string being passed to it from main function. In such case since I know that I can detect the end of string present in the character array using the null terminated character `'\0'` it should be ok even if I don't have the length. Does that sound ok?

Comment: @RBT It does, but it will probably cause multiple calls to `strlen()` wich can become inefficient.